# Searching strategy to efficiently load data from service or server?

Tags: java, c#, performance, search, design-patterns

This question is not very a language-specific question, it's some kind of pattern-related question, but I would like to tag it with some popular languages that I can understand here.

I've not been very experienced with the requirement of efficiently loading data in combination with searching data (especially for mobile environment).

My strategy used before is load everything into local memory and search from there (such as using LINQ in C#).

One more strategy is reload the data every time a new search is executed. Doing something like this is of course not efficient, also we may need to do some more complicated things to sync the newly loaded data with the existing data (already loaded into local memory).

The last strategy I can think of is the hardest one to implement, that is lazily load the data together with the searching execution. That is when the search is executed, the return result should be cached locally. The search should look in the local memory first before fetching new result from the service/server. So the result of each search is a combination of the local search and the server search. The purpose here is to reduce the amount of data being reloaded from server every time a search is run.

Here is what I can think of to implement this kind of strategy:

- When a search is run, look in the local memory first. Finishing this step gives out the local result.
- Now before sending request to search on the server side, we need to somehow pass what are already put in the result (locally) to exclude them from the result when searching on the server side. So the searching method may include a list of arguments containing all the item IDs found by the fisrt step.
  With that searching request, we can exclude the found result and return only new items to the client.
- The last step is merge the 2 results: from local and server to have the final search result before showing on the UI to the user.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but what I feel not really good here is at the step 2. Because we need to send a list of item IDs found on the step 1 to the server, so what if we have hundreds or thousands of such IDs, sending them in that case to the server may not be very efficient. Also the query to exclude such a large amount of items may not be also efficient (even using direct SQL or LINQ). I'm still confused at this point.

Finally if you have any better idea and importantly implemented in some production project, please share with me. I don't need any concrete example code, I just need some idea or steps to implement.

Comment: I would have a message sent whenever something you are interested in changes, this way you can keep your in memory copy up to date and always as in memory speed.

Comment: I have to wonder if this question would be better served over at [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) since it seems a bit broad for this site -- but that is not a guarantee that it would be better served over there. Please read [What is the difference between stackoverflow and programmers.stackexchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76890/162852) and [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570/522444) for more on this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure if what I'm interested in here can be known beforehand, because the search is run on demand based on the keyword typed by user. That means theoretically all the items are what I'm interested in (because the user may search/find any of them). All the items may occupy hundreds or even thousands of MBs. Thanks.

Comment: Correct you might need a couple of GB of memory.  For a server this is fairly normal thing to do. Downloading a few GB over a slow connection to a client isn't such a great idea but neither is contacting the DB directly from a client.  I suggest you have a service close to the database which caches all the data you need and you have a client which sends queries to it.  BTW 16 GB costs about $100.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so you mean the search is run against a server having some cached database. I'm afraid that I don't have such a dedicated server. Anyway thank you for what you shared, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment....

Concerning step 2, you know you can run into many problems:

#### Amount of data

Over time, you may accumulate a huge amount of data so that even the set their id's gets bigger than the normal server answer. In the end, you could need to cache not only previous server's answers on the client, but also client's state on the server. What you're doing is sort of synchronization, so look at [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm) for inspiration; it's an old but smart Unix tool. Also [git push](https://matthew-brett.github.io/curious-git/git_push_algorithm.html) might be inspiring.

Basically, by organizing your IDs into a tree, you can easily synchronize the information (about what the client already knows) between the server and the client. The price may be increasing latency as multiple steps may be needed.

#### Using the knowledge

It's quite possible that excluding the already known objects from the SQL result could be more expensive than not, especially when you can't easily determine if a to-be-excluded object would be a part of the full answer. Still, you can save bandwidth by post-filtering the data.

#### Being up to date

If your data change or get deleted, your may find your client keeping obsolete data. The client subscribing for relevant changes is one possibility; associating a (logical) timestamp to your IDs is another one.

### Summary

It can get pretty complicated and you should measure before you even try. You may find out that the problem itself is hard enough and that achieving these savings is even harder and the gain limited. You know the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it does not solve or provide any solution to my problem, but it does point out some things I should take into consideration, +1 for your helpful share.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem by thinking local and remote are two different data sources,

1. When a search is triggered, the search is initiated against both data sources (local - in memory and server)
2. Most likely local search will result in results first, so display them to the user.
3. When results returned from the server, you can append non duplicate results.
4. Optional - in case server data has changed and some results remove/ or changed, update/remove local results and update the view.

Comment: Well I think your approach works in some case but what if we need to perform a sorting or grouping on the whole result? So the merging step should be done before showing anything. Anyway now I think what I'm trying to achieve is something fairly complicated and should not be used, using some dedicated server (as a cache) may be what we should follow (of course it requires more hardware and money). I would like to give you 1 upvote for what you shared however :)